# ionic 5 use "ion-nav" to navigate to simple pages with back button

Tags: angular, navigation, back-button, ionic5, ion-nav

I'm very new to ionic and have this simple question which to my surprise i cannot find my answer anywhere i search.

what i want is to implement simple page navigation just like this :
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/nav

the source code below the mobile gives javascript codes yet i want in angular/ionic code.

any other documentations use sophisticated codes and for some reason i cannot understand it.

how could i archive this goal with the most simplest code possible for IONIC-5/Angular(using 'ion-nav')?

HTML:

this is what i have gone so far:

```
<ion-nav root="rootPage">
  
  <ion-header translucent>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Nav</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content fullscreen>
  <ion-list  *ngFor="let page of techs"> 
   
    <ion-item button (click)="showDetail(page)"> 
        <ion-label>
          <h3>{{page.title}}</h3>
        </ion-label>
      </ion-item> 
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
</ion-nav>
```

TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.page.scss'],
})
export class ListPage implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  rootPage:any;
  techs = [
    {
      'title': 'Angular',
      'icon': 'angular',
      'description': 'A powerful Javascript framework for building single page apps. Angular is open source, and maintained by Google.',
      'color': '#E63135'
    },
    {
      'title': 'CSS3',
      'icon': 'css3',
      'description': 'The latest version of cascading stylesheets - the styling language of the web!',
      'color': '#0CA9EA'
    },
    {
      'title': 'HTML5',
      'icon': 'html5',
      'description': 'The latest version of the web\'s markup language.',
      'color': '#F46529'
    },
    {
      'title': 'JavaScript',
      'icon': 'javascript',
      'description': 'One of the most popular programming languages on the Web!',
      'color': '#FFD439'
    },
    {
      'title': 'Sass',
      'icon': 'sass',
      'description': 'Syntactically Awesome Stylesheets - a mature, stable, and powerful professional grade CSS extension.',
      'color': '#CE6296'
    },
    {
      'title': 'NodeJS',
      'icon': 'nodejs',
      'description': 'An open-source, cross-platform runtime environment for developing server-side Web applications.',
      'color': '#78BD43'
    },
    {
      'title': 'Python',
      'icon': 'python',
      'description': 'A clear and powerful object-oriented programming language!',
      'color': '#3575AC'
    },
    {
      'title': 'Markdown',
      'icon': 'markdown',
      'description': 'A super simple way to add formatting like headers, bold, bulleted lists, and so on to plain text.',
      'color': '#412159'
    },
    {
      'title': 'Tux',
      'icon': 'tux',
      'description': 'The official mascot of the Linux kernel!',
      'color': '#000'
    },
  ];

  showDetail(page:any){
    const tech = techs.find(tech => tech.title === title);
    nav.push('nav-detail', { tech });
  }
}
```

P.S: `nav.push('nav-detail', { tech });`  gives error (i dont know what is nav here)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like it's explained in **[the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/nav)** The `ion-nav` is actually used in some very specific scenarios.

> Nav is a standalone component for loading arbitrary components and pushing new components on to the stack.

And

> Unlike Router Outlet, **Nav is not tied to a particular router**. This means that if we load a Nav component, and push other components to the stack, they will not affect the app's overall router. **This fits use cases where you could have a modal, which needs its own sub-navigation, without making it tied to the apps URL.**

So if you're using Angular, most of the times you could just use the `NavController` which, behind the scenes, uses the Angular Router.

Please take a look at this **[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-65135988?)**.

There you can see a very simple example of a page that shows a list of items, and clicking on each items opens a "details" page:

[image: Demo]

When reviewing that demo project, please pay attention to the `app-routing.module.ts` file  (where the routes for the home and the details modules are defined) and also to the way the data is sent from the `HomePage` to the `DetailsPage`.

```
// app-routing.module.ts file

// ...
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "home",
    loadChildren: () =>
      import("./pages/home/home.module").then(m => m.HomePageModule)
  },
  {
    path: "details/:id",
    loadChildren: () =>
      import("./pages/details/details.module").then(m => m.DetailsPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: "",
    redirectTo: "/home",
    pathMatch: "full"
  }
];
// ...
```

```
// home.apge.ts file

// ...
public openItem(itemId: number): void {
  this.navCtrl.navigateForward(["details", itemId]);
}
// ...
```

```
// details.page.ts file

// ...
ngOnInit() {
  // "id" is the name of the parameter in the
  // app-routing.module.ts file:
  // ==> path: "details/:id",
  const itemId = +this.route.snapshot.params.id;

  this.item = this.itemsService.getItem(itemId);
}
// ...
```

I'd definitely recommend you to take a look at the **[Angular Router docs](https://angular.io/guide/router)** and the **[Ionic - Angular Navigation docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/navigation)** in order to get more familiar with the routing system used in Ionic 5.